# Zxing barcode scanner don't display product info

Tags: android, zxing

I have the zxing scan integrated into my application but the problem is that when the user scans something the projects information appears. I don't want this I want the scanner after scanning to return to my application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Just launching the captureactivity from intent code posted

Comment: Doesn't that require the barcode scanner to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you launch the app by Intent, so I don't think you're even launching Barcode Scanner.

I think you are launching your own internal copy, which you don't need and should remove anyway. The real app will respond to your Intent.

Do this: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I dont' want the prompt for them to select a scanner app to appear if they have multiple apps that can scan. I want to force them to use the internal one

Comment: @user1634451 You should remove the internal one and just rely on the real BarcodeScanner app, that will handle all situations far better than you can hope to yourself. At the very least if you are going to gank the code you should move it inside of your own package instead of leaving it with the real package name.

Comment: The problem with relying on the real app is that the user has to have it installed which is not always the case.